# Too many characters in string literal mvc button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm changing my `@Html.ActionLink("Name","Action", new { @class='button', @id='addItemEIqM'})` to buttons so that they can contain `data-roles`and work with handling for dynamic list controls.

Leaving me with:

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ExistingManager","Pa_Ipv4")'" data-containerPrefix="@ViewData['ContainerPrefix']" class="button" id="addItemEIpM"/>
```

I am getting the error `Too many characters in character literal`, what is illegal in what I have written?

Comment: You can add `data-` attributes to `@Html.ActionLink()` so seems unnecessary to do this

Comment: Initially tried that but it didn't work so went down html  button. Shall look into that again then.

Comment: It just needs to be `new { data_containerPrefix = ViewData["ContainerPrefix"], @class = "button" }` (you need to use the underscore character, not a hyphen)

Comment: That would explain it then... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use single quotes for string literals in C#. Single quotes are for character. Your error is:

```
...erPrefix="@ViewData['ContainerPrefix']"...
```

you should use double quetes:

```
...erPrefix="@(ViewData["ContainerPrefix"])"...
```